# why is the date field messing up when im reading from xlsx to java?

Tags: java, excel, oop, logic, structure

I have the date column format set as M/d/yyyy in excel, however, when I am reading the cell value in Java, the date appears to be "05/Jan/2021", I'm confused about whats happening? can anyone help me with what I'm doing wrong?

```java
XSSFWorkbook wb1 = new XSSFWorkbook(fis1);   
XSSFSheet sheet1 = wb1.getSheetAt(0);     //creating a Sheet object to retrieve object  
Iterator<Row> itr1 = sheet1.iterator();    //iterating over excel file  
ArrayList recipientids = new ArrayList();

for (Row row : sheet1) { // For each Row.
    Cell cell = row.getCell(4); // Get the Cell at the Index / Column you want.
    Cell cell2 = row.getCell(5);
    CellType type = cell2.getCellType();
    if (type == CellType.NUMERIC) {
        Date date = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat DateFor = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy");
              String dateString = cell2.toString();
        String newdate = dateString.replace("-", "/");

        arraylist.add(cell+"-"+newdate);
    }
}
```

However, when I try to format, I get unable to format/parse exceptions.

Comment: Do not use `SimpleDateFormat` anymore. It is outdated for so many years now ...

Comment: can you please suggest me a way around?

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested, don't use `SimpleDateFormat` or even `Date`. There is a new Date and Time API in Java since Java 8.

Check the following, it might help:

```java
XSSFWorkbook wb1 = new XSSFWorkbook(fis1);   
XSSFSheet sheet1 = wb1.getSheetAt(0);     //creating a Sheet object to retrieve object  
Iterator<Row> itr1 = sheet1.iterator();    //iterating over excel file  
ArrayList recipientids = new ArrayList();
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/yyyy");

for (Row row : sheet1) { // For each Row.
    Cell cell = row.getCell(4); // Get the Cell at the Index / Column you want.
    Cell cell2 = row.getCell(5);
    CellType type = cell2.getCellType();
    if (type == CellType.NUMERIC) {
        String dateString = cell2.toString();
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateString, dateTimeFormatter);
        System.out.println(date.format(dateTimeFormatter)); // Formats this date using the specified formatter.
    }
}
```

Comment: @NewBond007, did this help? Let me know if something is unclear.